# "with the exception of..." in the context of a contract

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the following use of *with the exception of* natural?

The contract may not be terminated, with the exception of a medical reason.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic, "except for" is what you want. *With the exception of **Fido**, **all of the dogs** are long-haired.*  The object of the phrase (here, Fido) must be of the same type as the subject in the main clause.  *With the exception of **Bill**, **everyone here** plays golf.* The object of the exception-phrase is singled out of its class. In your example, "medical reason" is not a member of class "contract".

Comment: How about "Students are not allowed to bring any animals to the school, with the exception of service dogs"?  Here, "animals" is the object of the verb "bring."

Comment: I will broaden it to say that the exception refers to any plural noun in the main clause, whether grammatical subject or object. *He gave her his keys, with the exception of the key to the garage.*  The important fact relevant to your question is that the exception must belong to the nominal class from which it is being singled out.

Comment: And it needn't be confined to subject or object, and the class need be only semantically plural: *With the exception of {Thursdays}, I'm in the city {every day this month}.*

Comment: Can I use "except in the case of" in my original example? 'The contract may not be terminated, except in the case of a medical reason."

Comment: **except in the case of** would be grammatical, but as I mentioned above, "except for" is the common phrase. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22terminated%20except%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en   *The contract may not be terminated except for medical reasons.*   (though that is rather vague -- is a headache sufficient?)

Comment: What if "medical condition" is used instead of "medical reason" and another exceptional element such as"an emergency deemed acceptable by common consent," is added, as in "The contract may not be terminated except in case of a medical condition or an emergency deemed acceptable by common consent"?

Comment: Those phrases are grammatical, and "a medical *condition*", it could be argued, is more specific than "medical reasons". "an emergency ... consent" is quite a mouthful but still rather vague. To say whether those qualifying phrases would afford the contracting parties the necessary legal protections is well outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Is there any difference between "except in case of" and "except in the case of"?

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question.